# There may be a little bug on Stack Overflow Markdown

Tags: support, markdown

When I'm editing [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245176), the list followed by code is not supported by Stack Overflow. I clicked <kbd>code</kbd> Multiple times, but it didn't work.

The same is Meta.

[image]

While the bold followed by code is OK:

**class Node**

```
public class Node<T>: NSObject, NSCoding {
// ... code
```

Comment: √, Active reading. [<http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance> (the last section)]